# Why QFont and QFontInfo family poperties of one widget are different

Tags: c++, qt

So, these two lines:

```
  qDebug() << "ff1" << m_titleTreeView->font().family();
  qDebug() << "ff2" << m_titleTreeView->fontInfo().family();
```

returns this result:

```
ff1 "Verdana"
ff2 "Noto Sans"
```

My widget is QTreeView. Why it happen? I think that my result should be the same.

All other props like pixelSize, weight, and point size are similar.

QT 5.11.0
GCC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that [`QFont::family()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#family) gives you the **requested** font name, while [`QFontInfo::family()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#family) gives you the effective name.

In more details, whenever you as for a specific font via the constructor of `QFont`, for instance, the OS looks for the best match via a rather elaborated font matching algorithm. `QFont` keeps the information of what you asked for, while `QFontInfo` gives you information about what you got.